# After rebooting or upgrading the app, my Android widget stops updating

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-widget

Whenever I reboot my phone or upgrade the app (on my test device and on `Android` emulator) the widget stops updating until I create a new instance of the widget. Then both instances of the widget will start updating again. I assume it's something with calling the `onUpdate()` on old `WidgetIds`, but I can't figure it out.
Here's a small snipped of my code.

```
 public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

private static final String refresh = "b_refresh";

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewAppWidget.class);
    intent.setAction(refresh);
    intent.putExtra("appWidgetId", appWidgetId);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(refresh.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

EDIT: Here's my manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".NewAppWidget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/new_app_widget_info" />
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Can we see the matching portion of AndroidManifest.xml (where you register the provider)?

Comment: @greeble31 Sure, I've edited the question with the .xml.

Comment: Hmm. That `EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS` really shouldn't be there (b/c it's not an action), but I can't see what would be causing your problem. 1.) How exactly do you know the widgets are not updating? 2.) How about logging calls to `onUpdate()` and dumping `appWidgetIds` each time?

Comment: I've tried removing that flag, but kept it because I didn't notice any change in doing so.

So when I upgrade the app or reboot my phone, the refresh button stops working. However, when I logged `onUpdate` in my primary app (has the same code) `onUpdate` isn't called for the existing widget. The old instance only calls `onUpdate` again when I create a 2nd widget instance.

Comment: I suspect that `onUpdate()` is indeed being called after a reboot, otherwise you would have said, "the widget disappears on reboot." Your problem sounds more like the `Intent` is not getting to the activity the way you expect. Could you please carefully explain what you mean by "primary app" and "same code" (perhaps add this to your question)? Are we dealing with two apps installed simultaneously? And also, when you say "upgrade," I take that to mean, "increment `android:versionCode` and re-install." Is that what you mean?

Comment: @greeble31 Sorry, I may have over-complicated my explanation. There is only 1 app, this is just a copy of my other project so that I can test freely.

But not only when I increment the version does it break, it's if I run the app in Android Emulator again even without making any changes. So in a way, the widget only responds to clicks or updates for the period after I create it. If I re-run the emulator, reboot my phone, or anything - the functions and refreshes will stop working.

Interestingly enough the font of the widget also reverts to default from my custom font while it's "broken".

Comment: I think I see it... add a call to `super.onReceive()` to your `onReceive()` function. If that fixes it I will attempt to explain what happened.

Comment: @greeble31 Wow, that actually fixed it. I had tried this before but was probably under different circumstances. What is it about `super.x` that solves this issue?

Thank you so much for bearing with me, my vocabulary for explaining Java isn't  too great. I wish I could give you rep, I've been looking all around to solve the update problems I've been having with widgets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a call to `super.onReceive()` to your `onReceive()`.

**Explanation**

If you look at the source for the base class `onReceive()`, you can see that it implements part of the framework logic for managing Widget lifecycle. (Also hinted at by the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html)). It handles `APPWIDGET_UPDATE` and is, in fact, what's responsible for calling `onUpdate()` in the first place. (E.g., when the system boots up, and it needs to draw your initial widget, it sends your app an `APPWIDGET_UPDATE`, which gets passed to `onReceive()`). So, I'm not 100% sure how `onUpdate()` was *ever* getting called, in your case, but I assume you have some code somewhere else that calls `updateAppWidget()`, and that's the only reason your widgets appeared to work even momentarily.